# void or any type as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, return-value, void

I was wondering if there is a solution to specify a template so that either `void` or any other type can be passed.
The following is a very simplified example, which should do nothing but return `void` if `TReturn` is `void` as well, or return the return value of the function (which returns `TReturn` too, but with the difference, that it actually is a type then).

```
template <typename TReturn>
TReturn Foo(std::function<TReturn()> function)
{
    if(std::is_same<TReturn, void>::value)
    {         
        // I am not sure what to put here   
        return function();
    }

    TReturn returnValue = function();
    // Do some stuff with the returnValue here
    return returnValue;
}
```

Now obviously what I did is wrong, since a function cannot return two different types. That's why I am asking, does anyone know the way to do this?

Any help is gladly appreciated

Comment: The wrong thing here is that you assume `TReturn` to be default constructible (which `void` isn't). Otherwise, it seems ok to me.

Comment: Another wrong is that you are trying to generate 'return void' instead of 'return'

Comment: @ManishBaphna yes, I do know that its wrong that's why I was looking for a way to make that statement true for non-`void` types and find another one for `void`

Comment: This seems odd -- when `Foo` is called with an argument that's a function whose return type is `void` you don't want to call it, but otherwise you do? If the goal is to **always** call the passed function all you need to do is call it: `return function();`. That's allowed when the return type is `void`, for this exact situation.

Comment: @PeteBecker You're right, I am sorry. Didn't notice that, of course I want to call the function regardless of the type that is passed to `Foo`. I am going to try your solution this instant.

Comment: @PeteBecker your solution would work, if it weren't for between the ` TReturn returnValue = function();` and `return returnValue;` I need to call another function which processes the `returnValue`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use overload:

```
template <typename TReturn>
TReturn Foo(std::function<TReturn()> function)
{
    TReturn returnValue = function();
    // Do extra stuff with return value.
    return returnValue;
}

void Foo(std::function<void()>)
{
    return function();
}
```

In C++17, you will have constexpr if

```
template <typename TReturn>
TReturn Foo(std::function<TReturn()> function)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same<TReturn, void>::value) {
        return function();
    } else {
        TReturn returnValue = function();
        // Do extra stuff with return value.
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for that, I also came up with that but I thought maybe there would be a solution with just one function. If it is not, I am going to use yours so thank you

Answer (score 2):

C++17 solution:

```
template <typename TReturn>
TReturn Foo(std::function<TReturn()> function)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same<TReturn, void>::value)
//     ^^^^^^^^^
    {         
        return function();
    } else {
        TReturn returnValue = function();
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you want the decision whether to return a value or not be made at compile time, AFAIK you're going to need two different functions (as suggested in antother answer).

Comment: thank you, I am really looking forward to being able to use this in C++17. It seems a lot more easy to use.